# TreePanel: Store is not loading

Tags: javascript, store, extjs6, treepanel

It's my first time working with ExtJS 6, and i'm having some problems with a TreePanel... Here are my scripts:

TipoCausasTree.js

```
Ext.define('Incidencias.view.main.TipoCausasTree',
{
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    xtype: 'tipoCausasTree',
    alias: 'tipoCausasTree',
    reference: 'tipo-causas-tree',

    requires: [
        'Incidencias.view.main.TipoCausasController',
        'Incidencias.store.TipoCausasTreeStore',
        'Ext.data.*',
        'Ext.grid.*',
        'Ext.tip.*',
        'Ext.tree.*'
    ],

    store: {
        type: 'TipoCausasTreeStore'
    },

    controller: 'tipoCausas',

    id: 'treepanelCausa',
    displayField: 'text',

    loadMask: true,

    collapsed: false,
    animate: false,

    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    root: {
        nodeType: 'async',
        text: "Tipos De Causas",
        id: 'root',
        expanded: true
    },

    listeners: {
        contextmenu: 'onCtxMenu'
    }
});
```

TipoCausasTreeStore.js

```
Ext.define('Incidencias.store.TipoCausasTreeStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

alias: 'store.TipoCausasTreeStore',

requires: [
    'Incidencias.model.TipoCausasModel'
],

model: 'Incidencias.model.TipoCausasModel',
autoLoad: true,

lazyFill: true,

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: context + 'listadoCausasTipoAdminTree.action',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: function(o) {
            return o.data || o.children
        }
    }
},
```

});

And TipoCausasModel.js

```
Ext.define('Incidencias.model.TipoCausasModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

fields : [
    {name:'id', type:'string'},
    {name:'text', type:'string'},
    {name:'iconCls', type:'string'},
    {name:'cls', type:'string'}
]
```

});

I can see the tree root in my panel, but my store is not loading... If I check network, nobody is calling to listadoCausasTipoAdminTree action...

Can you help me? Thanks

P.S. Srry for my english...

Update: When I execute 
Ext.getCmp('treepanelCausa').store.proxy.type
I get "memory" in console, and
Ext.getCmp('treepanelCausa').store.proxy.url
Is undefined...

Comment: Try to use store: 'Incidencias.store.TipoCausasTreeStore' without { type: .. }

Comment: I tried it, but if i don't use the alias, the store is not injected...
Btw, in console, when i type Ext.getCmp('treepanelCausa').store.proxy.url , the response is undefined... But the store is the one I implemented. 
Ext.getCmp('treepanelCausa').store.alias = 'store.TipoCausasTreeStore'

What can be wrong?

Comment: There is no URL property in TreeStore's proxy. Then it will be undefined in console. There is no any request in Network tab of console? Try to call store.load() method in afterrender listener of the treepanel. Also you havn't root and its childs properties in store. Not in proxy, in the store...

Comment: 1.- My TreeStore has url property: url: context + 'listadoCausasTipoAdminTree.action'

2.- No, there is no request in Network tab... I tried to call store.load() and it doesn't do anything...

3.- How should I set root and childs properties in store? ._.

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html

Comment: But my tree should be filled with my action response data, and childs property in root property is to fill my tree manually...

Comment: store.setRoot( root_object )

Comment: I tried setting the store root as you said, and it's still not working... I can see my root object in the tree panel, but there is still no request in Network tab, and obviously no data inside my tree :(